Troubleshoot Windows Update KB5045594 , KB5044273, KB4023057 failing with error code 0x800f0805 on Win 10 22H2 1000.19060.1000.0
On a computer with Windows 10 Home 22H2 64-bit build 1000.19060.1000.0, I am experiencing Windows Update failing to install the optional KB5045594 quality update, ending with error code 0x800f0805.
Windows Update is also attempting to download the update KB4023057 from October 2023, and the cumulative update KB50444273 from October 2024.
The status is a "Download error - 0x800f0805" for these two updates.
The Internet connection is working properly and I did many attempts, at different hours.
I increased the WinRE partition size by 250 MB, and its total size is currently 1.22 Go.
The troubleshooter of Windows Update was not able to fix the issue.
I could download the updates from the Windows catalog.
The miscellaneous installers were working, but always ended with a message that the update could not be installed.
How can I fix these update issues?
N.B.

The computer was originally in German language, and the French language pack has been added.
Would this possibly involve more than 250 MB of free space being required on the WinRE partition?

Today came an additional "advertisement" about Windows 11 version 22H2 being available for the computer. Just for the info, as I don't think this causing the problem.



“Would this possibly involve more than 250 MB of free space being required on the WinRE partition?” - The question is why do you only have 250MB of free space. You should have a lot more, Windows 11, has nothing to do with your issue.

What we really need is the Windows Update log show the source of the failure. None of those updates are associated with the WinRE security patch. Your failures are for a different reason

Can you tell us what the last cumulative update that your system successfully installed? That will tell us your actual build number cause it’s not 19060 has that exceed that current build number of the current cumulative update

@Ramound: Thank you. As the computer is by a customer, I cannot currently answer which cumulative update the system successfully installed ; I can check next time that I will be doing maintenance for his PC.
